# How do I link a GitHub repository to a Google Colab notebook?

Tags: git, google-colaboratory, git-clone

I have created a GitHub repository and I want to link it to my Colab notebook, but I am unable to do that. I have used the following command to get a clone of git repo:

```
! git clone link/to/your/repo
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal: repository 'link/to/your/repo' does not exist
```

Can someone please point out my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: what is the link that you are trying to clone? It may not be a valid link.

Comment: I'm using the following command line:    ! git clone link/to/your/repo

Comment: `link/to/your/repo` should be the link to GitHub repo that you want to clone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**When you use in Colab website:**

You can simply go to [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) and you can choose 'GitHub' on the box which you can see when you just go to the Colab site and login. Colab will automatically redirect you to github in order to authorize your github account. Then you can choose repository to use at Google Colab!

**When you use in local CLI:**

You need to check out the URL that you provided in command.
It MUST BE a valid git(hub) url.

Answer (score 3):

Create a personal access token as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Once done, just call

```
pat = 'Token here'
!git clone https://{pat}@github.com/username/repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to clone all of your **Files, Folders, Data** and etc from your **GitHub repository to Google.colab**

Before you follow the step you should **sync** your **Google.colab** with your **Google.drive** because it **needs space to store your data.**

Open a line code in your notebook in google colab and run this :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Go to your Files in Google.colab and create a new folder with your repository name with this path :

Files/Content/"YOUR TEMPLATE NAME"

Then follow these steps:

1. open google colab and create a notebook.ipynb OR use that notebook you using currently.
2. open a code line and type `! apt-get install git`
3. open another line code and type !git clone `https://github.com/"YOUR USER NAME"/"YOUR GITHUB REPOSITORY WANT TO ADD "`

You can find the right path of your repository from this path :

1. open your GitHub
2. go to the repository you want to clone
3. click on CODE ( the green button ) on the right corner of your repository and then click on HTTPS
4. you will see the URL then click on Copy

It will clone all of your data and everything that you want from GitHub to Google.colab

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are an absolute beginner, here's a tip pros may omit because it might be obvious.
All these solutions worked for me as soon as the code was made public but while it was private, no chance.