# Installing and using the code of a github repository into a Google Colab notebook

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I would like to train the model (in Pytorch) that is in this git repo: https://github.com/jurgisp/pydreamer

However I don't have a GPU, so I am wondering: how can I install all the code and dependencies of this github repository into a Colab notebook ? is it possible ? How ?

Thanks a lot

p.s: this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553747/how-do-i-link-a-github-repository-to-a-google-colab-notebook](https://here) only shows how to import .ipynb files present in Gihub into Colab, which is **not** what I am looking for